# What are Primative and Non-Primative data types in Python?

Tags: python, types

Google said: primitive data types include Integers, Float, Strings and Boolean, the non-primitive data types are Array, List, Tuples, Dictionary, Sets and Files

But Google also said that Python don't have such thing called Primative or Non primative. I'm quited confusing right now.

When I run the code help(int), help(str), help(list), i found out that every data types in python have some build in methods in it, which looks like an object. Does it means that all data types in Python are non primative?

Comment: The fundamental of Python is based on variables something like JavaScript. There is no need to write variable type when you define it. Just when you initialize it and pass value to it, Python know the type based on variable name.

Comment: In Java terms, there are no primitive data types in Python. Everything is an object.

Comment: There is no such thing as a primitive type in Python

Comment: If you're going to include details that you got from Google and ask questions about those details then you should include references (links) to the relevant pages so we can read them. The [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) are numerics, sequences, mappings, classes, instances and exceptions.

Comment: Is there a non-primitive integer (i.e. nullable type) in python?